# "Invalid value encountered in intersects" when comparing polygons with shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I've seen "invalid value encountered in intersection" before, and it seemed like adding a check for `if a.intersects(b)` was the fix for that. Now I'm getting a warning from `intersects()` itself. Any idea why `intersects()` would be throwing warnings?

My code looks like this:

```
results = []
for geom in geom_list:
    if target_polygon.intersects(geom) and target_polygon.intersection(geom).geom_type != 'Point':
        results.append(geom)
```

`make_valid()` is being called elsewhere, so I don't think that's the issue.